# Failing to install Maven POM-file from local repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to compile a Maven project (I'm very new to Maven) with the following pom-file:

```
 <artifactId>logtool-examples</artifactId>
 <description>Tools for analyzing state logs produced by the Power TAC
  simulation server</description>
  <groupId>org.powertac</groupId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <exec.args></exec.args>
  </properties>

  <!-- Sonatype OSS repo for resolving snapshot modules -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories> 

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powertac</groupId>
      <artifactId>logtool</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

As you see, the project (logtool-examples) has a dependency on a .jar that's supposed to be online (logtool), but currently isn't, so I compiled the .jar in a local directory and installed it, using the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=../logtool/target/logtool.jar -DpomFile=../logtool/pom.xml
-DgroupId=org.powertac -DartifactId=logtool-examples -Dversion=1.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

However, when I try to compile the file, I still get the warning:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.powertac:logtool:jar:1.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

even though I installed the POM-file and got a message that it was installed. Maven then proceeds to look for the .jar in the online repository.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your artifactId "logtool-examples" from the install command does not match the artifactId in your pom.xml file (logtool).

Comment: Oh, I thought the artifactId is supposed to be that of the target, not that of the installed file... Thanks!